# tensorflow.js mobilenet await net.infer is not working

Tags: tensorflow, artificial-intelligence

mobilenet is loaded
const result = await net.classify(webcamElement); is ok

but

const feature = await net.infer(webcamElement); isn't working
console.log(feature); is empty

here are CDN

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@latest/dist/tf.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@tensorflow-models/mobilenet"></script>
```

Do net.infer work with all tensorflow version?